# How can I modify a char* in DLL?

Tags: c++, c, winapi

When I pass a char* as a parameter to a DLL, I can get a new char* when I "return" a char* from DLL, but I can't get it done when I just use that char* parameter and return nothing.

This DLL function is OK, seems I can pass a char* to DLL.

```
void getStr(char *str){
   print("%s\n", str);
}
```

This is OK, too. It seems I can modify a pointer inside DLL.

```
void setInt(int a, int b, int *sum){
   *sum = a + b;
}
```

But there is no any luck when the pointer points to a char array.

```
void setStr(char* str) {
    char tmp[] = "From DLL";
    int len = strlen(tmp) + 1;
    str = (char*)malloc(len);
    memcpy(str, tmp, len);
}
```

I try to call this DLL function from a c++ program like this:

```
int main()
{
    char tmp[] = "Hello World!";
    setStr(tmp);  // I hope I can get "From DLL" here.
    std::cout << tmp;
}
```

The output is still "Hello World!", nothing happened after I try to get a new char*.
If I set the return value of DLL function to char* and get the return value in c++ program, everything is fine, but I can't just use parameter to do it.

Did I miss something?

Comment: The issue is unrelated to the callee being in another module. You'd see the same behavior if everything were in a single executable image. If you are passing data into and out of DLLs, make sure you understand [Potential Errors Passing CRT Objects Across DLL Boundaries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/potential-errors-passing-crt-objects-across-dll-boundaries).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To modify given string buffer, modify given string buffer.

```
void setStr(char* str) {
    char tmp[] = "From DLL";
    int len = strlen(tmp) + 1;
    memcpy(str, tmp, len);
}

int main()
{
    char tmp[] = "Hello World!";
    setStr(tmp);  // I hope I can get "From DLL" here.
    std::cout << tmp;
}
```

To modify the pointer, pass a pointer to the pointer.

```
void setStr(char** str) {
    char tmp[] = "From DLL";
    int len = strlen(tmp) + 1;
    *str = (char*)malloc(len);
    memcpy(*str, tmp, len);
}

int main()
{
    char tmp[] = "Hello World!";
    char* ptmp = tmp; // character array is NOT a pointer, so add a pointer to modify
    setStr(&ptmp);  // I hope I can get "From DLL" here.
    std::cout << ptmp;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works fine!!!
Is there any rules about that? Like you must use pointer to a pointer?

Comment: @hzh Just your ordinary rules, when transferring ownership. While the code in this answer produces the desired result, it also leaks memory. It's generally safer to not allocate resources a caller is required to release. But then, it's generally safer to not write C or C++ code at all.